# Can I handle alert inside UIWebViewDelegate?

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

```
<script language="javascript">
    alert("Hell! UIWebView!");
</script>
```

I can see the **alert message inside my UIWebView** but **can I handle this situation?**

**Update:**

I'm loading a web-page into my UIWebView:

```
- (void)login {
    NSString *requestText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@?user=%@&password=%@", DEFAULT_URL, user.name, user.password];    // YES, I'm using GET request to send password :)
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestText]];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

The target page contain a JS. If user name or password is incorrect this JS show alert.
I have not any access to its sources.
**I want to handle it inside my UIWebViewDelegate.**

Comment: do you want do something else when alert is called?

Comment: Handle how? With JavaScript, you can redefine the alert() function to do whatever you want it to do, e.g. call your own function; is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "contain a flash" you mean the page you're loading into your web view has an Adobe Flash movie in it, you're out of luck, I'm afraid. Mobile Safari doesn't support Flash, and most likely never will.

In the general case, if you want JavaScript running in a web view to communicate with the native app hosting it, you can load fake URLs (for example: "myapp://alert?The+text+of+the+alert+goes+here."). That will trigger the [`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:) delegate method. In that method, inspect the request, and if the URL being loaded is one of these internal communications, trigger the appropriate action in your app, and return `NO`.

Answer (score 15):

A better solution to this problem is to create a Category for UIWebView for the method

```
webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:
```

So that you can handle the alert event in any way that you'd like. I did this because I don't like the default behavior of UIWebView when it puts the filename of the source in the UIAlertView title. The Category looks something like this,

```
@interface UIWebView (JavaScriptAlert) 

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame;

@end

@implementation UIWebView (JavaScriptAlert)

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    UIAlertView* dialogue = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [dialogue show];
    [dialogue autorelease];
}

@end
```

Comment: I agree this solution is better. Seems like this is what PhoneGap uses. With this you can just call alert('message') in your javascript and you can do whatever calls you like when the page loads.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to do it:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    JSContext *ctx = [webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
    ctx[@"window"][@"alert"] = ^(JSValue *message) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"JavaScript Alert" message:[message toString] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    };
}
```

Note: only tested on iOS 8.