# Disable js alert in UIWebView in ios7

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, ios7

I used to disable js alert in UIWebView by overriding

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame;
```

as mentioned by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1585854/1263403).

Now with ios7&xcode5, the above code has the compile error: `WebFrame: expected a type`

There is no `WebFrame` anymore? Anyone know about this?

Comment: The `webview:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:` is a private method. Apple might have changed this in iOS 7. Thus you going to have to find an other way to do this.

Comment: Well, it is not in the official header of `UIWebView` nor is it in any delegate. That would make it a private method, Apple might reject you for using it. I was available in OSX but never on iOS

Comment: @rckoenes have a look at the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Webkit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html it is a delegate. I used it before. But now it looks like it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: That is the OSX reference and **not** the iOS reference of [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

Change `WebFrame *` to `id` or import the header from webkit.

Comment: Which header for ios?