# UIWebView just not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, google-visualization

I'm trying to get Googles Chart Api to work on a UIWebView but i just can't get it!

I created the UIWebView, set the delegate to self get my hands on any load error (using the `didFailLoadWithError` method, no errors btw), fire the load using a html string this way:

```
@interface GCAViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonGo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webViewChart;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;

@end

@implementation GCAViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.webViewChart.delegate = self;
}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
}

- (IBAction)buttonGoClick:(id)sender {
    NSString *str = @"<html>"
     "<head>"
     "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://www.google.com/jsapi\"></script>"
     "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"
     "alert('t1');"
     "google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});"
     "google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);"
     "function drawChart() {"
         "var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();"
         "data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');"
         "data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');"
         "data.addRows(["
                       "['Mushrooms', 3],"
                       "['Onions', 1],"
                       "['Olives', 1],"
                       "['Zucchini', 1],"
                       "['Pepperoni', 2]"
                       "]);"
         "var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',"
             "'width':400px,"
             "'height':300px};"
         "var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));"
         "chart.draw(data, options);"
     "}"
     "</script>"
     "</head>"

     "<body>"
     "<div id=\"chart_div\"></div>"
     "</body>"
     "</html>";
    [self.webViewChart loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];

}

@end
```

and nothing happens! No errors, no messages, nothing!

can anyone help?

Extra info: this is a test app designed to do only this...

**EDIT 1:** after some debug i got a fix that the error is related to the function `DrawChart`. If i remove the function declaration the `alert('t1')` happens just fine...

Comment: What's the value(address) of your self.webViewChart?

Comment: @bsarr007 its the UIWebView itself... i updated and posted all the code...

Comment: Did you check the IBOutlet on Interface builder, is the webview outlet connected to the property ?

Comment: @Malloc yes it is connected correctly... i can change other properties and load a more simple html ("<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>")

Comment: Can you implement the `webViewDidStartLoad:` delegate method, set a breakpoint inside and see if it gets called at all

Comment: @Malloc it does... finished gets hit 2

Comment: Ok, what about `webViewDidFinishLoad:` delegate method?

Comment: You can try to put your HTML exemple code inside a .html file ans open it un a browser and verify the output.

Comment: @bsarr007 did it already. Works as expected...

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure the `alert()` function will run properly on the `UIWebView`, maybe that's the cause of the html content not being rendered. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565102/can-i-handle-alert-inside-uiwebviewdelegate

Comment: For charts there's also the native Core Plot framework: https://github.com/core-plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just enclose the width/height with quotes

```
"'width':'400px',"
"'height':'300px'};"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it... in the function, its not 300px/400px -> It cannot have the px at the end... weird...

Comment: I had to `NSLog` your str and run the output in a browser to find the bug. You were a few seconds faster than me in figuring it out but thanks for accepting the answer :)